# os.path.isdir() returns false

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to check if a folder exists by

```
path = r"This PC\Bassel's Note\Internal storage\Audiobooks"
print(os.path.isdir(path))
```

It always returns false even though the folder exists (It's the folder of my phone which is connected to the laptop).
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Paths don't start with `This PC`. Use `r'C:\Users\whatever'` instead. Or, to access your phone, use an appropriate protocol/library, e.g. [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol).

Comment: There's no library called mtp. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: I'm talking about the Media Transfer Protocol. A quick google search reveals multiple python implementations/wrappers. Since I have no experience with either of them, I won't recommend any.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `os.path` command, since your mobile phone is not a part of your computer's OS. You should use adb to try to list the folder's content and parse the result: if the folder exsits you'll get return code 0, meaning the command was executed successfully, otherwise you'll get a none 0 code.
Pay attention to the folder's name - it must be the name of the folder as it is in the phone's os, and not as it reflects in your computer:

```
def check_phone_folder(folder):
    return os.system(f'adb shell "ls {folder} >/dev/null 2>&1"') == 0
```

Now if you call the function with an existing folder name you'll get `True` - `check_phone_folder('/data/local/tmp')`.
The `>/dev/null 2>&1` part will supress the output of the `ls` command.
You also have to have `adb` installed in your computer.

Comment: Using adb (which requires USB debugging to be enabled) looks like overkill to me.

Comment: I can't install ADB because I'm unable to install M2Crypto which is necessary for ADB

Comment: Which adb are you trying to install? Is it adb.exe (which isn't really an installation, it's an executable that you have to download to your computer) or some python module? My answer requires adb.exe.